# Quarkus @Inject settings from application.properties in @WebFilter

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to `@Inject` some settings from `application.properties` in `@WebFilter`, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate com.foo.www.PageFilter
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.createFilter(ManagedFilter.java:77)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:591)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:566)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder.bootServletContainer(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:517)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting com.foo.config.GlobalConfig com.foo.www.PageFilter.globalConfig
    at com.foo.www.PageFilter_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.www.PageFilter_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.www.PageFilter_Bean.get(Unknown Source)
```

The config itself is as follows:

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "global")
public interface GlobalConfig {
    List<String> domains();
}
```

Any workaround?

Comment: What does the code of filter look like?

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?